# Session value in non static field in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the current user id of the user and I tried the following code

```
ClsUser User = (ClsUser)Session["USER"];
```

but it shows error that it should write in the non static function..so my question is is how to get the current session value in static field

Comment: Use this HttpContext.Current.Session["USER"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using static function you need to use

`HttpContext.Current.Session`   so you can directly reference the namespace in the static function

try somethin like

```
ClsUser User = (HttpContext.Current.Session["USER"] as ClsUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution also check for `null` values

```
public static class UserInfo
{
    public static ClsUser showName()
    { 
        return (ClsUser)(HttpContext.Current.Session["USER"]);
    }
 }
```